# ema = df.column.ewma(ts, freq='ms'). What is the alternative for this code in the newer version of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

what will be the replacement for the parameter freq?

I've searched a lot for an alternative for this function in the new version of pandas but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. If anyone can answer this, it'll be a great help.

Comment: `ewm().mean()` ??

Comment: what will be the replacement for freq parameter then?

Comment: There is not a replacement.

Comment: @Trenton Is there a way to do the same thing. i.e. to calculate rolling exponential moving average for a time series data with unequal time intervals?

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and expected output? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: From the original documentation for `freq`: _Frequency to conform to **before computing statistic**_. Therefore, you can probably use [`.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) and `ewm`.